# NSFetchedResultsController performFetch function decodes all objects

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm very new to working with Core Data, so I'm probably doing something wrong.

I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` with `UITableView`, and the `performFetch()` function decodes all objects in the corresponding entity. However, I only want to decode a single of those in the `prepareForSegue` function, rather than to decode all of them right when the view is loaded, because decoding my custom object takes a while.

How would I fix it? Should I perhaps create an extra entity to contain the information I don't need to draw the table cells but only need in the next view, or would a one-to-one relationship be appropriate here?

Comment: What do you mean by "decode"?

Comment: and did you set a batch size on the fetch and use instruments to see what's really happening ?

Comment: @TomHarrington An attribute of the entity is a class which is encoded and decoded with the `NSCoding` protocol, and I have confirmed that the `init(coder:)` function of that class is being called once for each table view row (i.e. for each row in the database).

Comment: @Wain I'm not setting a batch size because I don't use this class in order to create the table view cells at all, so I'm trying to find out if there is a way to not decode those objects before I actually need them (which is in the `prepareForSegue` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this attribute is a Core Data "transformable" attribute, so that Core Data automatically invokes `NSCoding` methods when loading and saving data.

What you're seeing is normal for that design. When you fetch a managed object, it's a "fault" object with no property values. But as soon as you access *any* attribute values, *all* of them are loaded, including transformables. If that's a problem (and I second @Wain's suggestion of using Instruments to verify this before making changes based on assumptions), you have some options for dealing with it. In no particular order these include:

- Make the attribute "binary" instead of "transformable", and then add your own code to invoke `NSCoding` methods only when you actually need them. Both attribute types mean that the value is stored as a binary blob, the only difference is whether you call `NSCoding` methods or you let Core Data do it for you. With this change, you'd still load all of the attribute's data into memory, but you wouldn't run through the `init(coder:)` method until/unless you decide it's necessary.
- Use `propertiesToFetch` on the fetch request, along with setting `requestType` to `NSDictionaryResultType`. This would let you just not fetch this attribute, however it would give you `NSDictionary` objects instead of `NSManagedObject` (or your subclass).
- Move this attribute's data into a separate, related entity. Core Data fault firing loads the object's attribute values but not its related objects. So, you could fetch whatever entity you're fetching but not have any data to encode/decode until you decide to traverse the relationship.

Each of these would require some refactoring of code, with varying levels of convenience.

Comment: "Core Data fault firing loads the object's attribute values but not its related objects." I was wondering if this was the case or not. Either way, I set `propertiesToFetch` to exclude the one I didn't immediately need, and it seems to already do the job (even without changing the `requestType`) - Is this expected?

Comment: I did actually verify that all transformables were loaded by placing a breakpoint in the decoder initialiser.

Comment: Yeah, `propertiesToFetch` has some effect even without changing the result type. That's a relatively recent change I sometimes forget about. As for related objects, yeah that's true unless you use `relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching`. Verifying that `init(coder:)` is useful but it doesn't take the place of using Instruments to verify assumptions about where slowdowns occur.

Comment: I also did verify using `NSLog` statements that the slowdown did indeed occur there, as it took over 90% of the time spent in `viewDidLoad`. I'm not very familiar with Instruments yet.